# quantmod::getOptionChain doesn't return price dates

Tags: r, quantmod

I can pull an option chain to get a glance of it (e.g. with `quantmod::getOptionChain("SPY", Exp="2023-07-28")`), but it won't tell me what date those prices were from.

**Is there a lesser-known option that allows me to request the trade-date information from Yahoo?**

I don't want to do something like `Sys.Date() - 1` and then start checking if the market was open on that date, or if Yahoo doesn't have information from that date, etc. etc.

Comment: "...is there a lesser known option..." I see what you did there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo doesn't provide historical option chain data via their API. So the prices are as-of the `LastTradeTime` column in the output. I haven't used [ORATS](https://orats.com/) or `getOptionChain.orats()`, but you might be able to get historical data that way. You'd need to sign up and at least get an API key. Historical data may not be free.